# Non-generic factory creating Generic Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics

For some reason, I want create generic types objects of the following class

```
public class CrudResult<T>{
    T Data { get; set;}
    
    public static CrudResult<T> CrudTypeA(T data){
        return new CrudResult<T>(){
            Data = data;
        }
    }
}
```

As you guys know, this works fine by calling

```
CrudResult<T>.CrudTypeA();
```

Now, in the TypeA method, I need to use some methods available in the class Mapper (Automapper), which can be injected. This however, means that either the CrudTypeA should receive an instance of the mapper from the caller, or a non-empty constructor (using DI) should be created. Bad thing, then the method does not work anymore since the new CrudResult then needs to receive a Mapper aswell.

```
public class CrudResult<T>{
    private IMapper _mapper;
    public CrudResult(IMapper mapper) {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
    T Data { get; set;}

    //This breaks since this needs a mapper, and thus the static content doesnt work
    //Additionally, the class cannot be staticly referenced, since it needs to be instanciated 
    public static CrudResult<T> CrudTypeA(T data){
        return new CrudResult<T>(){ 
            Data = data
        }
    }
}
```

Now, we also have the factory way, where we have a factory create an object, the only problem is, then you need to declare the generic type on the class, which is not wanted for DI (If I understand correctly)

```
public class CrudFactory //<T> is needed here, but prevents DI
    {
        private IMapper _mapper;

        public CrudFactory(IMapper mapper)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public CrudResult<T> Create() {
            return new CrudResult<T>(_mapper);
        }
    }

I tried to do it with the factory approach
```

**The question**

Can I instanciate a class, with an parameter set which would otherwise be injected in static methods?

Comment: Why just don't use generic `Create` method, something like `public CrudResult<T> Create<T>(...)`?

Comment: ... or `CrudTypeA<T>(T data, IMapper mapper)`?

Comment: Also why do you think generics prevents DI?  what dependency injector are you using?